# What might cause YaST2 GUI to not appear on OpenSUSE Leap server

Tags: opensuse

I'm connected to OpenSUSE Leap 42.2 over SSH with X-forwarding. Consider the system completely fresh ("server" option) apart from

1. sshd enabled
2. installation of `kde-cli-tools-5` in order to get `kdesu`
3. installation of `dolphin` and `konsole`

I'm able to launch apps like `konsole` and `dolphin` using kdesu
However, when I run `kdesu yast2`, after entering the password into the prompt that appears, no YaST window appears. Nothing appears in the console after my command, and the logs are as follows:

`sudo cat /var/log/YaST2/`

```
Stage [1]: YaST2 startup level (1)...
Stage [1]: ==========================
        |-- declare -x BOOT_IMAGE="/multiboot/openSUSE-Leap-42.2-DVD-x86_64/linux"
        |-- declare -x Cmdline="ramdisk_blocksize=4096 isofrom=/dev/disk/by-label/MULTIBOOT:/multiboot/openSUSE-Leap-42.2-DVD-x86_64/openSUSE-Leap-42.2-DVD-x86_64.iso isofrom_device=/dev/disk/by-label/MULTIBOOT isofrom_system=/multiboot/openSUSE-Leap-42.2-DVD-x86_64/openSUSE-Leap-42.2-DVD-x86_64.iso loader=syslinux"
        |-- declare -x EFI="0"
        |-- declare -x EGL_LOG_LEVEL="fatal"
        |-- declare -x ESCDELAY="10"
        |-- declare -x HOME="/"
        |-- declare -x InitrdID="2016-11-09.27c0ed7f"
        |-- declare -x InitrdModules="scsi_mod scsi_dh_alua scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_rdac thermal libata libahci ahci mmc_core sd_mod cdrom sr_mod usb-common usbcore usbhid iscsi_boot_sysfs st sg"
        |-- declare -x Insecure="0"
        |-- declare -x InstsysID="2016-11-09.27c0ed7f"
        |-- declare -x Keyboard="1"
        |-- declare -x LD_LIBRARY_PATH=":/y2update/lib64:/y2update/lib:/y2update/plugin"
        |-- declare -x LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT="1"
        |-- declare -x Locale="en_US"
        |-- declare -x Manual="0"
        |-- declare -x MemFree="16237340"
        |-- declare -x OLDPWD
        |-- declare -x PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/lbin"
        |-- declare -x PWD="/"
        |-- declare -x RepoURL="<RepoURL (may contain sensitive information)>"
        |-- declare -x SHLVL="4"
        |-- declare -x SSHD="0"
        |-- declare -x SelfUpdate="1"
        |-- declare -x Sourcemounted="0"
        |-- declare -x StartShell="0"
        |-- declare -x TERM="linux"
        |-- declare -x Textmode="0"
        |-- declare -x UpdateDir="/linux/suse/x86_64-leap42.2"
        |-- declare -x UseSSH="0"
        |-- declare -x VNC="0"
        |-- declare -x WithFCoE="0"
        |-- declare -x WithiSCSI="0"
        |-- declare -x XCURSOR_THEME="DMZ"
        |-- declare -x Y2GDB="0"
        |-- declare -x YAST2_SSH="false"
        |-- declare -x YAST_DEBUG="/debug/yast.debug"
        |-- declare -x YaST2update="0"
        |-- declare -x ZyppRepoURL="<ZyppRepoURL (may contain sensitive information)>"
        |-- declare -x initrd="/multiboot/openSUSE-Leap-42.2-DVD-x86_64/initrd"
        |-- declare -x isofrom="/dev/disk/by-label/MULTIBOOT:/multiboot/openSUSE-Leap-42.2-DVD-x86_64/openSUSE-Leap-42.2-DVD-x86_64.iso"
        |-- declare -x isofrom_device="/dev/disk/by-label/MULTIBOOT"
        |-- declare -x isofrom_system="/multiboot/openSUSE-Leap-42.2-DVD-x86_64/openSUSE-Leap-42.2-DVD-x86_64.iso"
        |-- declare -x kexec_reboot="1"
        |-- declare -x loader="syslinux"
        |-- declare -x ramdisk_blocksize="4096"
        |-- declare -x ramdisk_size="512000"
        |-- Creating hook script list: preFirstStage...
        |-- Level 1 stages:
        |-- F02-hwinfo
        |-- F03-umount
        |-- F04-language
        |-- F05-cmdline
        |-- F06-terminal
        |-- F08-logging
        |-- F09-start
        |-- F10-cleanup
Stage [1]: Starting F02-hwinfo...
Stage [1]: ======================
        |-- Hardware detection for arch: x86_64
Stage [1]: Starting F03-umount...
Stage [1]: ======================
        |-- Trying to umount inst-sys exits with code: 32
Stage [1]: Starting F04-language...
Stage [1]: ========================
        |-- Language set to: en_US.UTF-8
        |-- Starting UTF-8 mode...
Stage [1]: Starting F05-cmdline...
Stage [1]: =======================
Stage [1]: Starting F06-terminal...
Stage [1]: ========================
        |-- Setup virtual console:
        |-- Lines: 67
        |-- Columns: 240
        |-- Type: linux
Stage [1]: Starting F08-logging...
Stage [1]: =======================
        |-- Set YaST2 LOG parameters:
        |-- Maximum log size: 5225153 kB
        |-- Maximum log count: 5
Stage [1]: Starting F09-start...
Stage [1]: =====================
        |-- Creating hook script list: preFirstCall...
        |-- Delegate program call to YaST2.call installation initial
Stage [call]: Starting prequalification checks...
Stage [call]: ===================================
        |-- Copying /etc/X11/xorg.conf.template to /etc/X11/xorg.conf
        |-- No SSH daemon running -> Medium SSH disabled
Stage [call]: Evaluate medium selection...
Stage [call]: ============================
Stage [call]: Check selected medium...
Stage [call]: ========================
        |-- Wished medium is: QT
        |-- Selected medium is: QT
        |-- X-Server is ready: 3781
        |-- Allow big memory allocation: overcommit_memory=1
        |-- Starting YaST2:
        |-- MODULE_NAME: installation
        |-- MODE_FLAGS:
        |-- MODULE_ARGS: ("initial")
        |-- MODE: qt
        |-- UI_ARGS: --noborder --auto-fonts --fullscreen
        |-- QT_IM_MODULE: xim
```

`sudo tail /var/log/YaST2/y2log`

```
2016-12-27 15:36:47 <1> roku(3277) [ncurses] NCurses.cc(RedirectToLog):574 isatty(stdout)yes
2016-12-27 15:36:47 <1> roku(3277) [ncurses] NCurses.cc(init):284 have color = 1
2016-12-27 15:36:47 <1> roku(3277) [ncurses] NCurses.cc(init):309 screen size 22 x 80
2016-12-27 15:36:47 <1> roku(3277) [ncurses] NCstyle.cc(NCstyle):315 Init xterm using color => 4 styles in xterm
2016-12-27 15:36:47 <1> roku(3277) [ncurses] NCurses.cc(SetTitle):476 Draw title called
2016-12-27 15:36:47 <1> roku(3277) [ncurses] NCurses.cc(init):321 NCurses ready
2016-12-27 15:36:47 <2> roku(3277) [ui-shortcuts] YShortcutManager.cc(checkShortcuts):85 Not enough widgets with valid shortcut characters - no check
2016-12-27 15:36:47 <1> roku(3277) [ui] YPushButton.cc(setRole):170 Guessing function key F1 for YPushButton "Help" at 0x7f3760005b60 from button role YHelpButton
2016-12-27 15:36:47 <3> roku(3277) [libycp] clients/menu.rb:212 Unknown option `defaultButton in PushButton widget
2016-12-27 15:36:47 <1> roku(3277) [ui] YPushButton.cc(setRole):170 Guessing function key F9 for YPushButton "Quit" at 0x7f37600063f0 from button role YCancelButton
```

What could be causing this silent failure of any GUI to appear? Are there any other packages that should be installed, or any other logs that can be checked?

Comment: Nothing seems to me to be indicative of an error.
The second log appears to have very little in it that is from launching the GUI version (I'm assuming that the ncurses entries are from the last time I ran it with `sudo` instead of `kdesu`).

Answer (score 1):

Why use the YaST GUI at all over an SSH connection? `yast` when called in the command line without x-forwarding, will draw an interface using ncurses within your terminal window. It's very friendly to resizing, etc.

It has all the same functionality that the GUI has, and is organized identically.